# Should the umbrella tag be renamed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have [car-insurance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car-insurance), [home-insurance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-insurance) and [insurance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insurance)  (and many more) but the tag for umbrella insurance is currently named [umbrella](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umbrella).

Wouldn't it be more consistent if this tag was called [umbrella-insurance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umbrella-insurance) instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an obvious one, so I've done the rename in a way that means [umbrella](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umbrella) will be a synonym for [umbrella-insurance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umbrella-insurance) in future.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and rename it.

There are only two questions with that tag, and the tag was just created a few days ago.